# Passing dynamic php values for Highchart graphs

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, highcharts

I have a php file and I connect it to the MySQL and fetch some values. I want to use these values in a .tpl file for showing graphs for which I am using Highcharts. I somehow am not being able to pass php values to the graph which is javascript. Please have a look at the code and tell me where am I going wrong.

My php code is:

```
$sqlStr = "select * from users where user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id'];

        $sqlQuery = mysql_query($sqlStr) or die(mysql_error()."<hr>".$sqlStr);

        if ( mysql_num_rows($sqlQuery) ) {

            $rowMyReport = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlQuery);

            $smarty->assign("value1",$rowMyReport['value1']);
            $smarty->assign("value2",$rowMyReport['value2']);
            $smarty->assign("value3",$rowMyReport['value3']);
            $smarty->assign("value4",$rowMyReport['value4']);
            }
```

Now I want to use these values for Highcharts to have a graph on my website. So I tried this:

```
$(function () {
$('#graph').highcharts({
    chart: {
        plotBackgroundColor: null,
        plotBorderWidth: 1,//null,
        plotShadow: false
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                style: {
                    color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'pie',
        name: 'Some-name',
        data: [
            ['title1',  <?php echo $value1; ?>],
            ['title2',       <?php echo $value2; ?>],
            ['title3',   <?php echo $value3; ?>],
            ['title4',    <?php echo $value4; ?>]
        ]
    }]
});
});
```

I call this graph in the .tpl file as such:

```
<div id="graph" style="min-width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

By giving hard-coded values the graph gets displayed, but when I use dynamic values(php values) graph does not displayed. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Probably the problem is that your values are string, instead of numbers. So use json_encode(). For more information visit our [website](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database)

Answer (score 2):

use `json_encode` for data , in your controller before passing it.

Comment: Could you please help me with the json_encode by giving an example from my problem. As in how do I access the individual values if I need them...

Comment: $smarty->assign("value1",json_encode($rowMyReport['value1'])); when you use highchart , you must json_encode(your_data) and pass it.

Comment: So I changed it in php and in .tpl, I used <?php echo json_encode($value1)?> .. Still the chart is not visible.

Comment: in your tpl file use <?php echo $value1;?>